# C++ program produces an exception to?

Tags: c++

why an error occurs An exception was thrown at address 0x003329B0 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: access violation occurred while writing to address 0xCCCCCCCC

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>
//------------------
using namespace::std;
//------------------
void input(int* size)
{
    cout << "Input pleas size your diapason of array";
    cout << endl;
    cin >> (*size);
};

void randomizer(int** array, int& size)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int result = rand() % size;
    result += 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= result; i++)
    {
        (*array[i]) = rand() % 100;
        if (i % 2)
        {
            (*array[i]) *= -1;
        }
    };
    (*array)[0] = result;
};
//------------------------------------------------------
int ittMOD(int** array)
{
    int result = 0;
    int itt = (*array)[1];
    for (int i(0); i < (*arrey[0]); i++)
    {
        if (itt < 0)
        {
            itt *= -1;
        };
        if (itt < (*array[i]))
        {
            itt = (*array[i]);
            result = i;
        };
        return result;
    };


};


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    //---------------------------
    int* array = new int;
    int size = 0;
    //---------------------------
    input(&size);
    randomizer(&array, size);
    cout << ittMOD(`&array);
    cout << endl;
    //cout << summELEMENTS(arrey);




    delete array;
    array = NULL;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Why the `C` flag ?

Comment: IIRC, Windows clears memory to `0xcccccccc` in debug bulds, so you've read some uninitialised memory and used it as a pointer.

Comment: `int i(0); i < (*arrey[0]); i++)` How can this compile ?

Comment: This is UB. `array` is pointing to a single `int`, but you are treating it like it's an array.

Comment: first time today, use std::vector

Comment: Why all those C-style casts?

Comment: `rand() % 100;` - don't do that. You are introducing bias in your random numbers. Use `std::uniform_int_distribution` instead.

Comment: `** array` - No. Just pass a `std::array` or `std::vector` instead - possibly by reference.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` - that's a *horribly bad* seed for a already quite bad random generator. All instances of your application started within the same second will get the same seed.

Comment: `array = NULL;
    return 0;` - first of all, you should be using `nullptr` rather than `NULL`. Secondly; why bother? You are terminating the application *anyway*, what does it matter what the value of `array` is?

Comment: `int* array = new int;` you are only allocating memory for a single integer.